# Javascript - Array pop and get first part of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have a path and I am trying to pop off everything after the last /, so 'folder' in this case, leaving the newpath as C://local/drive/folder/.

I tried to pop off the last / using pop(), but can't get the first part of the path to be the new path:

```
var path = C://local/drive/folder/folder
var newpath = path.split("/").pop();
var newpath = newpath[0]; //should be C://local/drive/folder/
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.slice()` instead of `pop()`

```
var newpath = path.split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/");
```

---

If you also need the last part, then just use `.pop()`, but first store the Array in a separate variable.

```
var parts = path.split("/");

var last = parts.pop();
var first = parts.join("/");
```

Now `last` has the last part, and `first` has everything before the last part.

---

Another solution is to use `.lastIndexOf()` on the string.

```
var idx = path.lastIndexOf("/");

var first = path.slice(0, idx);
var last = path.slice(idx + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the last statement to be like that:

```
var path = C://local/drive/folder/folder
path.split("/").pop(); // Discard the poped element.
var newpath = path.join("/"); // It will be C://local/drive/folder
```

**A note about `Array.pop`**: Each time you call the `pop` method it will *return* the last element and also it will *remove it from the array*.

Answer (score 1):

Could also use a regex:

```
function stripLastPiece(path) {
    var matches = path.match(/^(.*\/)[^\/]+$/);
    if (matches) {
        return(matches[1]);
    }
    return(path);
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/av7Mn/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the first part of the array.

var firstWord = fullnamesaved.split(" ").shift();

This disregards all things after the space.

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = "C://local/drive/folder/folder";
foo.match(/(.+\/)[^\/]+$/);
```

would result in: `["C://local/drive/folder/folder", "C://local/drive/folder/"]`

though i would prefer user1689607's answer